# Eslint - Leave Extraneous Parentheses

Tags: eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

I'm using VS Code to write Angular apps in TypeScript. I have the Prettier and ESLint extensions installed and I want to configure ESLint to **not remove** unnecessary parentheses. ESLint has a "no-extra-parens" and I'd like to turn it off.

As a background, the Angular projects have very low test coverage. With unit tests and integration tests I need to be sure not to break existing functionality. My company would have greater confidence in the formatting changes if the unneeded parentheses are left intact.

Comment: You will probably need to disable both `no-extra-parens` and `@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens`. There are instructions in the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules) (basically either use an `eslint-disable-` comment or set the rule to "off" in the configuration).